# Are the linear momentum and angular momentum the same in a simple pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum, torque, oscillators

If not, are they different in magnitude, direction, or both? Please be specific for a pendulum. A visual with the vectors would be nice too if the directions are different. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a system like a simple pendulum, with only a single dynamical degree of freedom, the dynamical descriptions in terms of different dynamical variables need to be equivalent.  You can write the equations of motion in terms of position and force, but for a simple pendulum that is not the most convenient, since there is a constraint—that the pendulum bob must remain in a fixed plane and at a fixed distance $\ell$ away from the fulcrum.  Writing the equation of motion in terms of the angular position and torque simplifies this somewhat.  Newton's Second Law for the angular motion becomes
$$I\ddot{\theta}=N,$$
where the moment of inertia is $I=m\ell^{2}$ and the torque $N$, calculated about the fulcrum, is $N=-mg\ell\sin\theta$.  This automatically encompasses the restriction that the distance of the bob from the fulcrum be $L$ (although the added restriction that the motion lies in a plane is still implicit).

Instead of $I\ddot{\theta}$ on the left-hand side of the equation of motion, we may use the derivative of the angular momentum $L$.  As a vector $\vec{L}=\vec{r}\times\vec{p}$, which for motion of the pendulum (with fixed $|\vec{r}|=\ell$) reduces to $L=I\dot{\theta}$, analogous to the linear momentum $\vec{p}=m\dot{\vec{r}}$.  The velocity $\vec{v}=\dot{\vec{r}}$ along the pendulum's circular arc is always $v=\ell\dot{\theta}$, so the magnitude of the momentum $p=\pm|\vec{p}|$ is related to the angular momentum by a constant factor, $L=\ell p$.

Note that the linear and angular momenta have different units.  $p$ has units of ${\rm mass}\cdot{\rm length}/{\rm time}$, while the units of units of $L$ are $({\rm mass})^{2}\cdot{\rm length}/{\rm time}$. A more sophisticated understanding of this differenced ties this to the fact that these are the momentum conjugates to variables with different units.  A component of the linear momentum $p_{x}$ is conjugate to a linear position variable $x$, while an angular momentum $L$ is conjugate to a angular variable (in this case $\theta$).  The product of a position variable and its conjugate momentum always has units of $({\rm mass})^{2}\cdot{\rm length}/{\rm time}$.  This clearly holds for $xp_{x}$ and also $\theta L$, since an angle like $\theta$ is formally dimensionless.